# How to implement correct Back behaviour when using Frame.Navigate?

Tags: xaml, navigation, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform app with multiple pages, a main page, a list page and a details page and use the following to navigate to List page:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ListPage), parameter);
```

When you are on the list page you can select an item which will launch a details page like so:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailsPage), parameter);
```

Which works fine, the parameter is a selected Id or information then when using the Back button which on a Desktop app or Phone uses:

```
this.Frame.GoBack();
```

This always returns to the MainPage, that is when go from Main, to List to Details hitting back goes to Main, how do I get the GoBack to Go back to the previous page, it always seems to go home rather than the user expected behaviour, an ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve seen this before when you subscribe to the HardwareButtons.BackPressed event (or whatever the equivalent is in a Win10 UWP app) on a page, but then don’t unsubscribe from it.  This means two event handlers get called when pressing Back, and both event handlers call Frame.GoBack().

I always subscribe to the event in the page’s NavigatedTo event, and unsubscribe in the NavigatedFrom event.

Could this be happening with your app?

If every page in your app should have the same behaviour, i.e. go back to the previous page, then subscribe to the back button event in the app class as suggested by @RoguePlanetoid in the comments:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
```

The OnLaunched method would be a good place to do this. Don't forget to tell the OS to display the back button when the app is running on a desktop or tablet:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

Then, add an event handler in the app class like this:

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

If you want different behaviour on different pages when back is pressed, i.e. ask the user to confirm losing their changes or something, then subscribe to the back button event in a pages OnNavigatedTo method (the code will be same as above), but make sure you unsubscribe in the page's OnNavigatedFrom event:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= this.OnBackPressed;

    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is possible I do subscribe multiple times - I do so on each page, so just need to unsubscribe then, that makes sense will try this and see if this resolves issue

Comment: Why don't you subscribe once in the App? No need to subscribe in every single page.

Comment: That's an improvement to say the least, and a better solution!

Comment: Could you please provide a code example for noobs ? thank you :)

Comment: @tieorange I've updated the answer with some code examples. Hope that helps.